# Centralize h2 inside a div?

Tags: html, alignment, center

I see this is a very simple matter, but I can't seem to solve it.

I need a `h2` to be displayed like so (the h2 I mean is the red area):

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bigu7.jpg)

As you can see, there is a main `div`, a child `section` and a couple more inside. The `h2` needs to be centralized within the child `section`. I need the `h2` to have `padding` with `background-color` around it. I've tried setting the `h2` as a `block`, but still nothing happens.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Thanks very much to you all. It really was simple but somehow I was making something real wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying a margin to center the h2 in css.

```
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

The normal text align should work just fine:

`h2{ text-align:center; }`

Answer (score 0):

margins is what you looking for

```css
#big-container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
   width: 300px;
   height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 110px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="big-container">
  <div id="container">
    <h1>
      Header
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```